# pg-promise: SQL Names ~ or :name does not seem to work with ParameterizedQuery

Tags: javascript, postgresql, postgresql-10, pg-promise

I am trying to use a [`ParameterizedQuery`](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/ParameterizedQuery.html) with [SQL Names](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#sql-names) inside its `text` parameter.

I know that the docs read that this parameter must be a `string` or a `QueryFile`.

Basically, what I'd like to do is something like:

```
import pgPromise from 'pg-promise';

const pgp = pgPromise();
const pq = new pgp.ParameterizedQuery({
      text: `
        SELECT $1:name from my_table
        where $2:name = $3;
        `,
      rowMode: 'array'
    });
const params = {user_col: 'user', id_col: 'id', id_value: 'XXX'};
try {
  return await this.db.any(pq, Object.values(params));
} catch (e) {
  console.error(e);

  return e;
}
```

What I get is an error like:

```
QUERY: {
[start:run]   text: '\n' +
[start:run]     '        SELECT $1:name from my_table\n' +
[start:run]     '        where $2:name = $3;\n' +
[start:run]     '        ',
[start:run]   values: [ 'user', 'id', 'XXX' ],
[start:run]   rowMode: 'array'
[start:run] }
[start:run] error: syntax error at or near ":"
```

Is it possible to use `:name` (or `~`) inside a `ParameterizedQuery`? The thing is, I really want my query result would be an Array of rows rather than an array of row objects, and ParameterizedQuery's parmater `rowMode` set to `array` seems the only way I can do this.

Comment: I guess it is not possible, as text queries as `Only the basic variables ($1, $2, etc) can be used in the query, because Parameterized Queries are formatted on the server side.` (see [here](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/ParameterizedQuery.html#text)). Am I right? Is there any alternative to return an array of rows instead an array of row objects from a query?

Comment: [Formatting Filters](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#formatting-filters) do not work within Parameterized Queries or Prepared Statements, as those are formatted on the server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Formatting Filters](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#formatting-filters) docs:

> Note that formatting filters work only for normal queries, and are not available within [PreparedStatement](https://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/PreparedStatement.html) or
> [ParameterizedQuery](https://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/ParameterizedQuery.html), because those are, by definition, formatted on the server side.

That note within official documentation was added following this question, because it came up a few times before. Hopefully, it will be more clear from now on.

Comment: Thanks, that clarifies the issue and it's great that you even updated the docs